# inline HTML elements behaves ( span vs button )

Tags: html, css

## inline HTML elements  behaves ( span vs button )

Way span element does not effected by width and Height but button does ,
i tried to set [dispaly : inline] to button but it still get height correctly as block elements.
span does not effectd by width and height but other inline elements are effected!!

[image]

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button{
  display:inline;
}

.box-1 , .box-2 {
    width: 300px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px 3px;
    border: 3px dashed gold ;
}
.box-1{
    background-color: #d66;
    min-height: 150px ;
    max-height: 200px ;
}

.box-2{
    background-color: #4e91e9;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="box-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="box-2">
        2
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <span class="box-1">span</span> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="box-1">button</button>

</section>
```

Comment: Typo in `dispaly:inline`

Comment: read *all* the answers in the duplicate. In each one you will find different information

Comment: The button element will behave as displayed as inline-block, even if you set it as inline, it's an exception to the norm